# Is it possible to display groupsummary in grouprow using XtraGrid v8.1

Tags: devexpress, grouping, footer, summary, xtragrid

I am working on XtraGrid v8.1.

I want all group summaries (even those that are positioned in group footers) are forcibly displayed in group rows under the corresponding column headers, and group footers are hidden.

Please see right side of image below:
[image: Like this]
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use event CustomDrawGroupRow and display summaries via your code.
In DevExpress DOC is a similar example with count:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomDrawGroupRow.event